# Using Aeson generics to construct JSON with a value as key holding another value

Tags: haskell, aeson

Toying a bit with the github gist API while trying to get down with the Aeson JSON library. I've run into a problem with the generated ToJSON instance, and I don't know exactly how to solve it.

I need to contain a value inside and the key that is associated to the value also needs to be a value and not a predefined key name. It's a bit easier to show. The desired output is,

```
{
    "public": true, 
    "description": "Something..", 
    "files": {"This Thing.md": {"content": "Here we go!"}}
}
```

where the value of the filename is holding the content, but currently I get,

```
{
    "public": true, 
    "description": "Something..", 
    "files": {"filename": "This Thing.md", "content": "Here we go!"}
}
```

Which isn't really what I need. The current code is,

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

data GistContent = GistContent
    { filename :: Text
    , content :: Text
      } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON GistContent

data Gist = Gist
    { description :: Text
    , public      :: Bool
    , files       :: GistContent
      } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON Gist
```

Under the assumption that it is possible, how would my datastructure need to look to get the desired output?.. And if that's not possible using the generics, how'd I got about it using the ToJSON instance (I can't quite figure out the structure there either)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from an incorrect schema. `files` can currently only contain one `GistContent`, which is unnecessarily limiting. Instead, you'd want to have a list of `GistContent`s:

```
data Gist = Gist
    { description :: Text
    , public      :: Bool
    , files       :: [GistContent]
    } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

Now consider another constraint on `Gist`: each `GistContent` must have a different `filename`. A data structure that would enforce this would be [`Data.HashMap.Strict.HashMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html#t%3aHashMap). Taking the `filename` out of `GistContent` and using the filename as a key:

```
data GistContent = GistContent
    { content :: Text
    } deriving (Show, Generic)

data Gist = Gist
    { description :: Text
    , public      :: Bool
    , files       :: HashMap Text GistContent
    } deriving (Show, Generic)
```

Everything works out.

Comment: Sweet, that did the trick :) Don't know why HashMaps never occurred to me, Aeson is still a bit of a stranger, but I'll hopefully get past that barrier pretty soon.

Comment: It may be instructive to look at the source for the `HashMap` instance (https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/Data/Aeson/Types/Instances.hs#L422) - 
`HashMap` is actually used as the internal structure in Aeson objects (https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/Data/Aeson/Types/Internal.hs#L171) which makes it particularly concise.

Comment: @icktoofay - did you mean `Data.HashMap.*Strict*.HashMap` above?

Comment: @Ganesh: I did, although both seem to work. Nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the manually written instance (see the [documentation for the class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t%3aToJSON)):

```
instance ToJSON GistContent where
   toJSON (GistContent { filename = f, content = c }) = object [f .= c]
```

I doubt if there would be any way to get this with your existing datatype with the automatically generated instances because all they can do is to follow the datatype using a standard scheme. Note that you can still use the generic instance for `Gist` because that will call the (non-generic) instance for `GistContent`.